# Any way to stop VMWare workstation from dropping SSH connections?

Tags: networking, ssh, vmware-workstation

I have VMWare workstation 8 with a few Linux guests.  I have had problems maintaining an active SSH connection to my VMs when they are in bridged mode.  I first read that the onboard realtek network cards were not well supported so I bought a Intel Pro/1000 GT card.  This supposedly had support.  But this made no difference.  Connections via SSH are active for about the first 3 minutes then hang and die.  I have changed the TCP Checksum offload on the Intel and Realtek NICs, but this only works some of the time and even then not for very long.  The best I could do was about 20 minutes before the connection was dropped.  Any ideas?

Comment: My connections sit open for weeks to one VM.  Where are you connecting from?  Are you crossing a NAT?

Comment: Are you virtual NICs of VM connected to same Virtual Switch or each NIC is connected to separate Virtual switch?

Comment: This is my desktop.  I tend to install the OS without a gui so I need shell access. The network is configure as bridged. There is nothing special about the virtual NICs, I have made no changes to the default setup. The OS and the VMs are using the Intel Pro/1000.